# any file to base 64 in javascript data loss

Tags: javascript, base64, ionic2, cordova-plugins

i am trying to convert media files to base 64 to upload to service in javascript. i am building an app in ionic 2 and capturing an image using MediaCapture plugin of ionic-native. then, converting that image to base64 as below:

```
MediaCapture.captureImage(options)
  .then(
    (data: any) =>{ //MediaFile[]
      let imageLocalUrl = data[0].localURL;
      console.log("imageLocalUrl:"+imageLocalUrl);
      this.base64Lib.convertToBase64(imageLocalUrl).subscribe((iBase64Str)=>{
        this.imageBase64 = JSON.stringify(iBase64Str).split("base64,")[1].replace(/(^")|("$)/g, '');
        console.log("imageBase64:"+this.imageBase64);
      })
      // console.log(data)
    },
    (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err)
  );
```

base 64 conversion:

```
convertToBase64(path){
return Observable.create((observer)=>{
  let filePath = path;
  console.log("path in b64lib:"+path);
  (window as any).resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path,gotFile,failed);

  function gotFile(fileEntry){
    console.log("fileEntry:"+fileEntry);
    // observer.next(fileEntry);
    fileEntry.file(function(file){
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onloadend = function(e){
        var content =  (e as any).target.result;
        // console.log("event:"+e);
        console.log("content:"+content);
        observer.next(content);
        // observer.complete();
      }

      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    })
  }
```

when i tried converting the console output to image i am seeing it as:
[image]

can anybody help me whats wrong in it?
i am using localUrl since, when i tried using file via fullpath its not able to find. i guess only persistent storage it work with fullpath.

base64 conversion reference: http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/80/how-to-convert-a-image-from-the-device-to-base64-with-javascript-in-cordova

Comment: `the console output` - are you sure the console output is complete. large console outputs can be truncated because nobody wants reams of data spewing out in a debugging tool

Comment: @JaromandaX -  you are right. when i give the base64 as image [src] its showing complete image. thank you very much.